# Check the status of "defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop"

Tags: shell, status

I want to write a simple shell script (for mac) that on execution either hides or shows all icons on desktop. To do this, it is clear:
`defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true/false` killall Finder.

To short cut this, I want to have an executable, maybe also a keyboard combi shortcut. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo doing stuff with icons

defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false
killall Finder

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose name contains ".command")' &
# exit
```

this is what I want to have:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo doing stuff with icons

#check status 

if defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop == true; then 
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false
killall Finder

else
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
killall Finder
fi

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to close (every window whose name contains ".command")' &
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying the same thing today and just found your post. This vvv works for me. I've put it in a Shortcut and pinned it to the menu bar.

```
if $(defaults read com.apple.finder CreateDesktop); then
    defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false; 
    afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff
else
    defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true;
    afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Ping.aiff
fi; killall Finder
```

Source: [Macmost post](https://macmost.com/10-ways-to-clean-your-mac-desktop.html)